# govendor doesn't work from cmd

Tags: bash, go, govendor

I try to use govendor in my project folder `/d/projects/go/src/github.com/user/dbot`

> govendor init

but bash returns

> bash: govendor: command not found

for installation I just follow instruction and use

```
go get -u github.com/kardianos/govendor
```

there is something else about what I need to know

```
$ go env
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=D:\projects\go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\VLADYS~1.KOC\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build082923582=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
```

Comment: This sounds like an path issue. If you just installed go try restart your terminal. If that dosn't work try adding C:\Go\bin to your path.

Comment: Restarted terminal and puted **C:\Go\bin** to my **Path** still not work for me.

Comment: You need to set `$GOPATH/bin` which is `D:\projects\go\bin` into your path.

Comment: doesn't help - **govendor: command not found**

Comment: restart windows machine helped! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you are doing is:

```
go get -u github.com/kardianos/govendor
```

then that just installs the `govendor` source files and dependencies. 
From `go help get`:

```
The -u flag instructs get to use the network to update the named
packages and their dependencies. By default, get uses the network 
to check out missing packages but does not use it to look for updates
to existing packages.
```

Your error:

```
bash: govendor: command not found
```

comes from the fact that the `govendor` binary is not under your `PATH`.

To fix this, first check that `$GOPATH/bin` is in your `PATH`, then run

```
go install github.com/kardianos/govendor
```

That will build `govendor` and put under `$GOBIN` (which by default is `$GOPATH/bin`).

Comment: first do go get -u github.com/kardianos/govendor then do govendor init. that worked for me (go 1.15)

Answer (score 1):

As [@theeddieh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1299930/theeddieh) mentioned, it's because the `$GOPATH/bin` is not in the `$PATH`.

Add the following to your `.bash_profile`, then restart your terminal app.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Finally, run `go get -u github.com/kardianos/govendor` to install. `govendor` should now be available globally.

Comment: i can't found govendor in whole disk files. but `go get -u github.com/kardianos/govendor` has been run

Comment: in $GOPATH, there is only `pkg` directory, no `bin` directory,see my answser

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls -alR /data/data/com.termux/files/home/go|grep vendor
drwx------  3 u0_a131 u0_a131 4096 Jul 30 17:02 govendor
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/kardianos/govendor:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/kardianos/govendor/@v:
-rw-------  1 u0_a131 u0_a131  372 Jul 30 17:02 govendor@v1.0.9
dr-x------ 14 u0_a131 u0_a131 4096 Jul 30 17:02 govendor@v1.0.9
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9:
dr-x------  2 u0_a131 u0_a131 4096 Jul 30 17:02 vendor
dr-x------  2 u0_a131 u0_a131 4096 Jul 30 17:02 vendorfile
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/cliprompt:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/context:
-r--------  1 u0_a131 u0_a131  1691 Jul 30 17:02 vendorFile.go
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/doc:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/help:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/internal:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/internal/gt:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/internal/pathos:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/internal/vfilepath:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/internal/vos:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/migrate:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/pkgspec:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/prompt:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/run:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/vcs:
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/vendor:
-r--------  1 u0_a131 u0_a131 1494 Jul 30 17:02 vendor.json
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/kardianos/govendor@v1.0.9/vendorfile:
-r--------  1 u0_a131 u0_a131 3475 Jul 30 17:02 vendor.go
```